# Identify current process is child process in Python

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

In Python 2.7, is there's a way to identify if the current forked/spawned process is a child process instance (as opposed to being starting as a regular process). My goal is to set a global variable differently if it's a child process (e.g. create a pool with size 0 for child else pool with some number greater than 0).

I can't pass a parameter into the function (being called to execute in the child process), as even before the function is invoked the process would have been initialized and hence the global variable (especially for spawned process).

Also I am not in a position to use freeze_support (unless of course I am miss understood how to use it) as my application is running in a web service container (flask). Hence there's no main method.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Sample code that goes into infinite loop if you run it on windows:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

p = Pool(5) # This should be created only in parent process and not the child process

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: It might help to show some code pertaining to how you fork a process and where you'd like to identify

Comment: Thanks inspectorG4dget for replying, I have added a sample snippet above for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the pool creation into the main section to only create a multiprocessing pool once, any only in the main process:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(5)
    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))
```

This works because the only process that is executing in the `__main__` name is the original process. Spawned processes run with the `__mp_main__` module name.

> create a pool with size 0 for child

The child processes should never start a new multiprocessing pool. Only handle your processes from a single entry point.

Comment: Hi Poke, thanks for replying, as I said in my question, I don't have the option for a main method (it's a web service application). And the code is just an example. Also the point of having a pool with Zero workers or None is exactly for the same reason, i.e. the child process doesn't need the pool object. The reason why the pool is global is so I can reuse the pool across multiple requests.

Comment: Ah, I understand. But you really shouldn’t launch child processes from a web service thread. That’s bound to cause problems. Instead, use some background workers to perform your tasks. For Flask, the most common solution for that would be to use [Celery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/), an asynchronous task framework.

Comment: Celery seems interesting. I'll have to redo my application to fit into this model though, but should get the job done. Trying to understand if it's multi-threading or multi-processing. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest restructuring your program to something more like my example code below. You mentioned that you don't have a `main` function, but you can create a wrapper that handles your pool:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, freeze_support

def f(x):
    return x*x


def handle_request():

    p = Pool(5) # pool will only be in the parent process

    print(p.map(f, [1, 2, 3]))

    p.close() # remember to clean up the resources you use
    p.join()

    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support() # do you really need this?

    # start your web service here and make it use `handle_request` as the callback
    # when a request needs to be serviced
```

It sounds like you are having a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377). You shouldn't be making a pool of processes global. It's just bad. You're giving your subprocesses access to their own process objects, which allows you to accidentally do bad things, like make a child process join itself. If you create your pool within a wrapper that is called for each request, then you don't need to worry about a global variable.

In the comments, you mentioned that you want a persistent pool. There is indeed some overhead to creating a pool on each request, but it's far safer than having a global pool. Also, you now have the capability to handle multiple requests simultaneously, assuming your web service handles each request in their own thread/process, without multiple requests trampling on each other by trying to use the same pool. I would strongly suggest you try to use this approach, and if it doesn't meet your performance specifications, you can look at optimizing it in other ways (ie, no global pool) to meet your spec.

One other note: [multiprocessing.freeze_support()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.freeze_support) only needs to be called if you intend to bundle your scripts into a Windows executable. Don't use it if you are not doing that.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Well I have a web service application, and it does some number crunching. Instead of having to create the process pool every single time a request is received, it's best to create the pool once and for all, and just submit tasks etc. I do agree that having a global variable is some what dangerous, but then how else can I create a reusable process pool? (instead of initializing the pool for every single request).

Comment: @Developer: update your question and provide the example code that is actually relevant to your case. What is your web-framework? How do you invoke your app? Have you considered `celery`? Why are you managing processes yourself? (e.g., you could let `gunicorn` to provide worker processes). Btw, nothing in this answer suggests that multiple pools are created; there is a single pool.

Comment: @Sebastian, as you may realize it's not easy to post a snippet of web service application, and even if I did, it'll be big enough and not easy for you to test it out, hence kept the example to the point / primary question. That said.. your point of using gunicorn, that's already the case, but that's for external requests, I am interested in executing a certain function only (which runs slow as there's a lot of number crunching) in a multiprocessing fashion. So I don't think gunicorn will be a solution (also Flask is the web service provider)

Comment: @Developer: obviously, [create a dummy example that demonstrates the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e.g., compute a Fibonacci number specified in the request using a process pool. It is ~20 lines to create a simple wsgi-app: `def app(environ, start_response): ...` it is even simpler using `flask`.

Comment: @Developer See edit. I don't have enough experience with using web services to give you a more comprehensive solution, but J.F. Sebastion's suggestions are a good starting point if this modification isn't enough for you.

Comment: @skrrgwasme: you should not create a new process pool for each request; the previous version of your answer with a single process pool was better